# How to implement the function of deleting an array?

Tags: c++

Help add the delete function, I'm not sure if the memory is cleared automatically.

```
template<class T1>
auto auto_array(T1&& _Size) {
    return new int64_t[_Size]{};
}
template <class T1, class... T2>
auto auto_array(T1&& _Size, T2&&... _Newsize)
{
    auto result = new decltype(auto_array(_Newsize...))[_Size];
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < _Size; ++i) {
        result[i] = auto_array(_Newsize...);
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {

   auto _Tor = auto_array(3, 2, 7);

   return 0;
}
```

do not offer a vector please this is a holivar.
I already have a code with a vector.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204127/discussion-on-question-by-nigan-how-to-implement-the-function-of-deleting-an-arr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I have to say that this is not the C++ way to achieve such functionality. Use a STL container or RAII concept.

You have to implement a delete function template to clean up the allocated memory. You have to pass the sizes to this function because the pointer doesn't know the sizes:

```
#include <cstdint>

template<class T1>
auto auto_array(T1&& _Size) {
    return new int64_t[_Size]{};
}

template <class T1, class... T2>
auto auto_array(T1&& _Size, T2&&... _Newsize)
{
    auto result = new decltype(auto_array(_Newsize...))[_Size];
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < _Size; ++i) {
        result[i] = auto_array(_Newsize...);
    }
    return result;
}

template <class T1, class T2>
void delete_auto_array(T1&& ptr, T2&&)
{
    delete[] ptr;
}

template <class T1, class T2, class... T3>
void delete_auto_array(T1&& ptr, T2&& _Size, T3&&... _Newsize)
{
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < _Size; ++i) {
        delete_auto_array(ptr[i], _Newsize...);
    }
    delete[] ptr;
}

int main() {

    auto _Tor = auto_array(3, 2, 7);
    delete_auto_array(_Tor, 3, 2, 7);

    return 0;
}
```